# Nagios installation issue

Tags: nagios

make install - commandmode

```
/usr/bin/install -c -m 775 -o nagios -g nagcmd -d /usr/local/nagios/var/rw

 chmod g+s /usr/local/nagios/var/rw
```

External command directory configured

make install-config

```
/usr/bin/install -c -m 775 -o nagios -g nagios -d /usr/local/nagios/etc

/usr/bin/install: invalid group ‘nagios’

make: *** [install-config] Error 1
```

During Nagios core installation steps I got the above error, I have created

the group already

```
useradd -m nagios

useradd: user 'nagios' already exists

groupadd nagcmd

groupadd: group 'nagcmd' already exists

 usermod -a -G nagcmd nagios

 usermod -a -G nagcmd apache

 pwd
```

Please advise to proceed further

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below commands to complete it:

```
make install-groups-users
usermod -a -G nagios apache
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

You have been created 'nagcmd' user group, but use 'nagios' group name in install command.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
adduser nagiosLearn
groupadd nagiosTest 
usermod -aG nagiosTest nagiosLearn
```

When you are installing `nagios`

```sh
./configure --with-command-group=nagcmd
```

In the group name, you have to used the same group name where you have assigned the user.